# Intel X vs Intel K CPU gaming

Tags: cpu, multi-core, chipset

I'm looking to build a PC, and want eight RAM slots. For eight RAM slots, I need to choose motherboards with X-series [chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipset), which requires an X-series CPU.

Intel example of K-series CPU: *Core i7-9700 K*

Intel example of X-series CPU: *Core i7-9800* **X**

**Q1:** What suggested type is there currently?

**Q2:** Could it use an X-series CPU for gaming, even that's not the intended use for the X-series?

**Q3:** Would I lose a lot in choosing a X-series CPU, compared to the more normal K-series?

Comment: What exactly is a "type X" processor?  Are you talking about Intel Xeon?  As currently written your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

> Could it use an X-series CPU for gaming, even that's not the intended use for the X-series?

An [i7-9800X](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189122/intel-core-i7-9800x-x-series-processor-16-5m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html) CPU would be significantly faster than an [i7-9700k](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186604/intel-core-i7-9700k-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html).

Beyond the performance improvements offered by the additional memory channels, and the additional cores available through [Hyperthreading](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/hyper-threading-intel-definition,5746.html), there is no real difference between those two processors.  Both of those processors can be considered a "gaming processor".

Any performance improvements an [HEDT](https://www.custompcreview.com/wiki/hedt/) processor provides will be due to the additional memory bandwidth and PCIe bandwidth that [LGA2066](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_2066) allows.

Comment: Your other two questions are out of scope.  Question seeking a hardware recomendation will not be answered here at Super User.  Your other question is not actually clear.  I suspect I know what you are actually asking, which I attempted to address, by confirming that a HEDT CPU would provide better performance.